# How to get properties of a component without using event

Tags: reactjs, dom, state, react-component, rerender

Consider I have a parent component Like

```
const [ top , setTop ] = useState(0);
const Parent = () => {
    return (
        <div style={{ display:"flex" , flexDirection:"column" }} 
            onScroll={ (e) => { setTop(e.target.scrollTop) } }>
            <Child parentTop={top} no={1} />
            <Child parentTop={top} no={2} />
            <Child parentTop={top} no={3} />
            <Child parentTop={top} no={4} />
            <Child parentTop={top} no={5} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here the child elements are re-rendered for every scroll
and 5 same child component are like :

```
const Child = ({ parentTop , no }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {"THIS IS CHILD COMPONENT"}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I want to console.log( no + " : reached top ") **when the parentTop is less then or equal to the offsetTop of the child**. offset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sad to see no one here to help me :(

But after many attempts I found an answer :)
We have to use useRef() hook for this.

Like...

```
const Child = ({ parentTop , no }) => {
    const refDiv = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        if(parentTop <= refDiv.current.offsetTop){
            console.log( no + " : reached Top" );
        } 
    },[parentTop]);
    return (
        <div ref={refDiv} >
            {"THIS IS CHILD COMPONENT"}
        </div>
    );
}
```